# Add custom activation function to be used with a string

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, activation-function

I followed [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66358/75968) response doing:

```
get_custom_objects().update(act_dispatcher)
```

Where `act_dispatcher` is a dictionary with all the activation functions I want to add like `{'fun_1':fun_1, 'fun_2': fun_2}`.

The first thing that caught my attention is that at the beginning, if I add nothing, `get_custom_objects()` returns an empty dict `{}`. After adding the function I check that each call to `get_custom_objects()` has what I said it to be.

However, I am getting `ValueError: Unknown activation function:<my_fun>`

I added the line

```
assert 'my_func', in get_custom_objects().keys()

tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='my_func')
```

And the assertion pass without problem having the error mentioned at the keras Dense init.

---

The error occurs at [deserialize_keras_object](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L334-L389) where:

- `custom_objects` is `None`
- `_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS` is `{}` (Probably this shouldn't be empty).
- `module_objects.get(object_name)` returns None (module_objects seams correct).

---

**Installation**

I am using an anaconda environment. Due to an error that I had first with `from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects` I installed `keras-applications` with `conda install -c conda-forge keras-applications`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can running those code without any error, you can try to change `from tensorflow.keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects` to `from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_custom_objects` see if it helps:

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_custom_objects
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

def my_func(x, beta=1.0):
    return x * K.sigmoid(beta * x)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation(my_func))

get_custom_objects().update({'my_func': Activation(my_func)})

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='my_func'))
```

Comment: So I added the Activation constructor as you said but still nothing. After adding it I get this output for `print(get_custom_objects())`: `{'my_fun': <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7fbc3c24b6d0>}`

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina how did you using your custom activation function? is like `model.add(my_fun)` or like `model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='my_fun'))` ? what error did you get? also what is your custom function look like?

Comment: `model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.Input(shape), tf.keras.layers.Flatten, tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='my_fun')])`

Comment: I added info about the error, I also went to the place of `Tensorflow` where the error occurs.

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina I edit the answer, let me know it helpful or not

Comment: Ok, got the error, I was using `keras.utils` instead of `tensorflow.keras.utils`!!! So clumsy of me and impossible for you to debug because I did not added the imports. Thank you. I will leave the question because it might help someone. Marked as solution.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused too about a minute, no problem, glad to help : )